# Update value of input after text

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint

I want to add a default value to an input field on an existing form when the page is loaded.  All of the inputs on the field have the same name and ID on this form.

```
<table>
    <tr><td>Name:</td><td><input id="MultiLookupPicker" name="MultiLookupPicker"/></td></tr>  
    <tr><td>Company:</td><td><input id="MultiLookupPicker" name="MultiLookupPicker"/></td></tr> 
    <tr><td>Department: </td><td><input id="MultiLookupPicker" name="MultiLookupPicker"/></td></tr> 

</table>
```

Here's the example http://jsfiddle.net/ljd144/6ocsLk6k/

How would I add a default value to the input immediately following the text "Company"?  Thanks!

Comment: assigning same id is not proper. Try assigning class.

Comment: have you tried `value="stuff"`?

Comment: @Vikash Yes, I agree, but I am modifying a form created by another system, and cannot change the form code itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `input` is not in your `td` so the `find` method won't work. You need to select the next `td` first.

```
 $( "td:contains('Company')").next("td").find("input").val("test");
```

I updated your fiddle with the right selector

[**JSFiddle updated**](http://jsfiddle.net/ksemsch/6ocsLk6k/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try it ..but **id must be unique**

```
 $( "td:contains('Company')").next().find("input").val("test");
```

NOTE: In your fiddle `$( "td:contains('Company')").find("input")` it always return empty array bcoz there is no `input` element that td , so use `next()` and `find the input`

**[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6ocsLk6k/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the same **id** on multiple element, it's very very bad and **will** lead to unexpected result.

to add a default value, you can do it in html :

```
<tr><td>Name:</td><td><input id="MultiLookupPicker" value="yourvalue" name="MultiLookupPicker"/></td></tr>
```

or in jquery :

```
$("$MultiLookupPicker").val("yourvalue");
```